# MQL4 '#include' - expressions are not allowed on a global scope

Tags: mql4

Is there a way to include file with is in a #define macro ? When I tried I got an error message.

```
#define FILE_PATH "myfolder"
#define FILE_NAME "myfile"
#define FULL_PATH (FILE_PATH + FILE_NAME)
#include FULL_PATH
```